# updating ingress nginx controller with new ACM SSL certificate is causing https connection not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ssl, nginx-ingress, amazon-elb

Our ingress controller configuration for nginx and aws load balancer

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: xxxx
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: https
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - appProtocol: http
    name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - appProtocol: https
    name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

example Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /main
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: main
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

We are experiencing an issue when changing ACM SSL certificate, after updating LoadBalancer configuration by updating kubernetes deployments, we observe that new certificate is associated with load balancer but the https connection is not working. The only way to make it work was by removing all ingress related resources: controller, jobs, load balancer and create it again, after all works.

I tried to restart nginx controller, I am thinking if ACM cert is saved somewhere in kubernetes during initializing of ingress nginx controller, and after the value of SSL cert the Load Balancer is updated but nginx ingress controller still keep reference of SSL certificate ?

How You guys are updating SSL ACM certs for nginx ingress controller which use aws network load balancer ? What is the correct way of updating nginx ingress controller after updating SSL cert from ACM ?

Thanks,
Igor

Comment: Nginx doesn't know about the certificate at all when using ACM to terminate at the load balancer. There is no potential for cache here. Can you explain what not working meant? Were you actually seeing the old cert?

Comment: @jordanm after changing service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert annotation for ingress nginx controller, https is not working, I don't know how to debug it but I was checking ingress nginx controller pod logs and the https traffic was not coming through, so does it mean that the load balancer was not letting it through ?  I haven't identify the issue, but found out that by removing all ingress related resources from kubernetes like controller, jobs, load balancer  and after creating everything again solve the problem.

Comment: Check the logs for aws-load-balancer-controller. If you don't have that installed, you need it for full load balancer functionality.

Comment: I had the same error, but I realized its because we were configuring a certificate generated in the wrong region. Once we corrected the region in the certificate, changing annotation worked well. Just in case if it helps anyone.

Comment: @boneys in my case all was ok with certificate, but I thought that certificate manager works globally ?

Comment: @jodanm yes so I checked the logs, I think my problem was related to fact that ingress was not updating load balancer. So when I update configuration related files for ingress controller and load balancer, how ingress is updating load balancer ?